# Mysql Master - Master Replication and mysql-bin.log Rotation issues

Tags: mysql, linux, hosting, database-replication, master-slave

I have successfully synced my primary and secondary databases using Mysql Master - Master Replication( guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mysql-master-master-replication ). Well I am stuck with a weird issue. Every time the mysql service is restarted the value of **mysql-bin.xxxxxx** file gets incremented(eg: mysql-bin.000005 to mysql-bin.000006) and it stops the master - master replication process. How can I prevent the mysql-bin file value rotation or is there any way to deal with this increment issue so that even if the rotation happens the replication wont get affected?
Thanks :)

### Update

As usual I had to find the answer for my own question, here is the solution for those who are facing the same situation. Just added the line **`log_slave_updates=1`** to my.cnf file in both the servers.

## Master - Master Repication:

### Primary my.cnf:

```
#bind-address=127.0.0.1
server-id=1
log_bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db=db_name_1
binlog_do_db=db_name_2
binlog_do_db=db_name_3
max_binlog_size=100M
log_slave_updates=1
auto_increment_increment=2
auto_increment_offset=1
```

### Secondary my.cnf:

```
#bind-address=127.0.0.1
server-id=2
log_bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db=db_name_1
binlog_do_db=db_name_2
binlog_do_db=db_name_3
max_binlog_size=100M
log_slave_updates=1
auto-increment-increment=2
auto-increment-offset=2
```

Comment: This question contains answer too...